# In WPF, create expander based on combobox input

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, visual-studio-2012, dynamic

I'm using this example to solve a larger problem, but since I'm new to wpf and C#, I've got to start somewhere right?  Alright, so what I want to do is create a new expander based on combobox input.  My current code for this is very simple.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<!-- MainWindow.xaml -->
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True" Text="Default Text" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="260" Height="30">
            <ComboBoxItem PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="method1" Name="method1>1</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="method2" Name="method1>2</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="method3" Name="method1>3</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="method4" Name="method1>4</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
//MainWindow.xaml.cs
Public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void method1(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("method1");
    }

    private void method2(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("method2");
    }

    private void method3(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("method3");
    }

    private void method4(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("method4");
    }
    //public class dynamicExpanderCreation
    //{
        //Here's where I'm assuming the class for dynamic creation should go.      
    //}
```

Instead of each one calling a method, I'd like to have them create an expander that is created based on the selection of the combobox.  For example, if you were to select 3, then an expander appears to the left, labeled 3.  Then if you select 1, an expander appears below the #3 expander, labeled 1.

I'm guessing you create a class in the MainWindow.xaml.cs file, and create a new instance of the expander per selection of the combobox.  I've found examples that are a little too complicated for me to follow based on my very simple task.  The examples I've looked at are [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/541453/DynamicallyplusCreatingplusanplusInstanceplusofplusUserplusControlplusinplusWPF), [here](https://zamjad.wordpress.com/2012/04/10/dynamically-loading-user-control/), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19518132/wpf-dynamically-created-buttons-and-expanders-control)

I'm not saying these examples are bad, just that at my experience level, I can't get any of them to work.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: are you using MVVM pattern?

Comment: I'm completely new to wpf, so I'm not familiar with that.  I'll read more about it now though.  But to immediately answer your question, I'd like to use some logical pattern, but I've never done anything in wpf.

Comment: you can better use the SelectionChanged Event of combobox,in that event you can get the selecteditem. did you try that?

Comment: Yes, I tried using SelectionChanged, but my problem isn't with the combobox logic, as much as figuring out how to dynamically create the expander from the combobox.

Comment: so you just want to know how to add a dynamic expander to the view ?

Comment: Yes, sorry if the question wasn't worded well.  I want to add an expander every time they make a selection from the drop down menu

Comment: you can just create a stackpanel/dockpanel/wrappanel and create an object of the expander and set properties and then add to the any of the panel using Expander expander = new Expander();
            dock.Children.Add(expander); where dock is the name of the panel

Comment: Can you give a short example in the answer section so I can try it out and accept your answer?

Comment: Your selection of controls is very counter-intuitive. A combobox selects one item. I would expect the last selection to be removed, not the new selection being added to the last.

Comment: Well, I need the user to be able to select from a list of 4 items.  They also need to be able to select the 4 items multiple times.  So that's the reason I'm using a combobox.  That way they can select what they want in the combobox, see it add an expander (which represents their selection), then the combobox resets, allowing them to add more if they would like.  If you know of something else that meets that criteria, I'd be more than happy to try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In WPF you need to put any of the panels like
>   stackpanel/wrappanel/dockpanel/Grid

```
<ComboBox Name="combobox" IsEditable="False" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged" Text="Default Text" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="260" Height="30">
                <ComboBoxItem>1</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>2</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>3</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>4</ComboBoxItem>
            </ComboBox>

            <StackPanel Name="dock">                   

            </StackPanel>
```

> And in the Codebehind

```
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var itemIndex = combobox.SelectedItem;
            Expander expander = new Expander();
            dock.Children.Add(expander);
        }
```

> Where dock is the name of your panel

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.  Another thing I mentioned in the question above was whether or not you could change the content of the new expanders being created based on the input from the combobox.  I know you can set parameters for the combobox by using something like <code>Expander expander = new Expander{Header="Test"}</code> .  Could you change the header based on which comboboxitem was selected?

Comment: so you want to set a header according to the item selected from the combox?

Comment: Since the code has changed so much, I'm just going to post a different question.  Thank you for all of your help.

Comment: what about your Expander header problem ? Is it solved ?

Comment: Not solved yet, but I reposted the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28556022/wpf-access-combobox-selected-item)