# WPF, Access combobox selected item

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, expander

I have a combobox that has four static possible selections, shown below

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Grid>
    <ComboBox Name="combobox" IsEditable="True" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged" Text="Default Text"
        <ComboBoxItem Name="ComboBoxItem1">1</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Name="ComboBoxItem2">2</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Name="ComboBoxItem3">3</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Name="ComboBoxItem4">4</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
    <StackPanel Name="dock">
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

I'm creating an expander for each combobox item that is selected using this method.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{

    var itemIndex = combobox.SelectedItem;

    Expander expander = new Expander { Header = this.combobox.Name };
    dock.Children.Add(expander);
}
```

I know I can access the combobox name, but I'm not sure how to access the comboboxitem name.  I've tried using

```
Header = this.combobox.ComboBoxItem.Name
```

And other variants of that, but I've had no success.  I'm just trying to make the header of each expander into the name of the comboboxitem.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Should `StackPanel` contain single child (corresponding to selected item), or it should add new `Expander` every time user select an item in `ComboBox`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var itemIndex = combobox.Text;
    string name = (combobox.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem).Name;
    var obj = dock.FindName("Exp_Name");
    if (obj == null)
    {
        Expander expander = new Expander();
        expander.Header = name;
        expander.Name = "Exp_Name";
        dock.Children.Add(expander);
        this.RegisterName(expander.Name, expander);
    }
    else
    {
        var element = obj as Expander;
        element.Header = name;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you explain, why you're using `as` without null-checking instead of cast operator?

Comment: Thanks for adding in the null check too.

Answer (score 3):

you can go like this:

```
    private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    { 
       var selectedItem= combobox.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem; 
       if(selectedItem!=null)
       {
           string name = selectedItem.Name;
           Expander expander = new Expander { Header = name };
           dock.Children.Add(expander);
       }
    }
```